# Entity-Component System : fear of losing type & readability

Tags: visual-studio, c++11, architecture, entity, components

I have a Entity-Component System.

**Components** : classes with data, but have no complex function
**Entity** : integer + list of Components (<=1 instance per type per entity)
**Systems** : a lot of function with minimum data, do complex game logic

Here is a sample.  A bullet entity `pewpew` is exploded, so it will be set to be invisible (at `#2`):-

```
class Component_Projectile : public ComponentBase{
    public: GraphicObject* graphicObject=nullptr;     //#1
    public: Entity whoCreateMe=nullptr;
    public: Entity targetEnemy=nullptr;
    //.... other fields ....
};
class System_Projectile : public SystemBase {
    public: void explodeDamage(Entity pewpew){ //called every time-step
        Pointer<Component_Projectile> comPro=pewpew;
        comPro->graphicObject->setVisible(false);     //#2
        //.... generate some cool particles, damage surrounded object, etc
    }
    //.... other functions ....
};
```

It works OK.

## New Version

Half year later, I realized that my architecture looks inconsistent.

- I cache all `game-logic object` using `Entity`.
- But cache `Physic Object` and `Graphic Object` by direct pointer. (e.g. `#1`)

**I have a crazy idea :**
`Physic Object` and `Graphic Object` should also be `game-logic object`!
They should be encapsulated into `Entity`.

Now the code will be (the change is marked with `#1` and `#2`):-

```
class Component_Projectile : public ComponentBase{
    public: Entity graphicObject=nullptr;                         //#1
    public: Entity whoCreateMe=nullptr;
    public: Entity targetEnemy=nullptr;
    //.... other fields ....
};
class System_Projectile : public SystemBase {
    public: void explodeDamage(Entity pewpew){ //called every time-step
        Pointer<Component_Projectile> comPro=pewpew;
        system_graphic->setVisible(comPro->graphicObject,false);  //#2
        //.... generate some cool particles, damage surrounded object, etc
    }
    //.... other functions ....
};
```

After playing them for a week, I can conclude pro/cons of this approach as below :-

### **Advantage**

**1. Drastically reduce couple between game logic VS graphic-engine/physic-engine**

All graphics-specific function is now encapsulated inside 1-3 systems.
No other game systems (e.g. `System_Projectile`) refer to the hardcode type e.g. `GraphicObject`.

**2. Dramatically increase flexibility in design**

Old vanilla graphic object is not just a graphic object anymore!

I can change it to something else, especially add special feature that is totally insane / too specific for physic/graphic engine, e.g.

- rainbow blinking graphic
- strange gravity, magnet
- swap in/out many physic-object type in the same Entity (not sure)

**3. Reduce compile time**
It is accidentally become a pimpl idiom.
For example, `System_Projectile` don't have to `#include "GraphicObject.h"` any more.

### **Disadvantage**

**1. I have to encapsulate many graphic/physic-object's functions.**
For example,

```
system_graphic->setVisible(comPro->graphicObject,false);
```

is implemented as

```
public: void setVisible(Entity entity,bool visible){
    entity.getComponent<Graphic_Component>()->underlying->setVisible(visible);
}
```

It is tedious, but not a very hard work.
It can be partially alleviated by `<...>`.

**2. Performance is (only) little bit worse.**
Need a few additional indirection.

**3. Code is less readable.**
The new version is harder to read.

```
comPro->graphicObject->setVisible(false);                //old version
system_graphic->setVisible(comPro->graphicObject,false); //new version
```

**4. Losing type + `Ctrl+space` is less usable**
In old version, I can easily `ctrl+space` in this code :-

```
comPro->graphicObject-> (ctrl+space)
```

It is now harder.  I have to think which system I want to call.

```
system_(ctrl+space)graphic->(ctrl+space)setVisible
```

## **Question**

In most code location, the advantage overcome the disadvantage, so I decided I will use the new version.

How to alleviate the disadvantages, especially number 3 and 4?
Design-pattern?  C++ magic?
I may use Entity-Component System in a wrong way. (?)

Comment: This is highly opinion based, I doubt you will get The One Correct Answer. In my opinion you should not use inheritance for an ECS. It forces all your components and systems to be dynamically allocated and accessed through pointers, which is bad for performance, readability and correctness. `ComponentBase` and `SystemBase` should not exist. Instead use something like a `template <class T> std::vector<T> components;` as a basis which should look something like [this](https://github.com/SuperV1234/ecst/blob/master/CODE_SAMPLE.md) when finished.

Comment: @nwp  Thank!   In your link, I notice that `position`, `velocity` and `acceleration` are 3 types of component.  I think it is very suitable for very simple program (`main` in the link).  ...... My case is a bit complex, I can't control those fields directly.  There is another library (not ECS) managing it in place.  I got `GraphicObject` as a bundle.     Therefore, I am left with 2 choices - expose the type `GraphicObject` to only a few systems (new version), or all systems (old version). ......   For  components that is totally a game logic, I can do as in the link.